# DLL converted from C++ .so unable to DllImport due to "Unable to find Entry Point"

Tags: c#, c++, .net, function, dllimport

Currently I have a legacy `bcl_engine_rule.so` file such that when it's `DllImport`-ed within a .cs file and running `dotnet xxx.dll` of the compiled C# file, the C# file was able make use of a function that was in the `.so` with no problem.

Now for the purpose of being able to debug the C# program on Windows, rather than having to test it by moving onto the Linux environment each time, I've gone through a painstaking effort of converting the `bcl_engine_rule.so` into a `bcl_engine_rule.dll` file (built all the individual dependencies too from scratch to individual .dll(s) ) so that I can import it on Windows. Having come across so many errors(which I'll outline below), I've decided to reduce the complexity of my library to the simplest I can to a point where I'm basically exporting a very simple function, but the same errors simply remain, which implies that I may be missing something simple.

The small reproducible library is something like(with a lot of stuff stripped away):

```
Fix2Winner2
- src
  - RulesEngine
    - RuleEngine.cpp
    - RuleEngine.h
  - bcl_rule_engine.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt
```

RuleEngine.h

```
#ifndef TESTRULEENGINE_H_
#define TESTRULEENGINE_H_

#include <string>

namespace Rules
{
class RuleEngine
{
public:
    RuleEngine();
    virtual ~RuleEngine();

    bool loadFromConfig(const std::string&);
    void setDebugMode ( int debug );

    static bool _debug;
    static bool getDebugMode() { return _debug; }

private:

};

}
#endif
```

RuleEngine.cpp

```
#include "RuleEngine.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace Rules
{

bool RuleEngine::_debug = false;

RuleEngine::RuleEngine()
{
    std::cout << "Creating Test Rule Engine object " << std::endl;
}

void RuleEngine::setDebugMode( int debug )
{
    if ( debug > 0 )
    {
        _debug = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _debug = false;
    }

    std::cout << "*** Setting debug mode to " << _debug << std::endl;

}

RuleEngine::~RuleEngine()
{
    std::cout << "Destroying Test Rule Engine object " << std::endl;
}

}
```

bcl_rule_engine.cpp

```
#include "RulesEngine/RuleEngine.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace Rules;

RuleEngine* ruleEngine=0;

extern "C"
{
int init_config_rule_engine( char* configFile, int debugMode)
{
    ruleEngine = new RuleEngine();  

    if ( !ruleEngine )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ruleEngine->setDebugMode( debugMode );

    if ( !ruleEngine->loadFromConfig( configFile ) )
    {
        return -2;
    }

    if (ruleEngine)
    {
        delete ruleEngine;
        ruleEngine = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
}
```

Now `init_config_rule_engine` is basically one of the function which I'm trying to run on my C# code. I've omitted the other one since it wasn't necessary to bring it in to reproduce the errors.

I'm using CMake within Visual Studio to compile the dlls. It was easier to do this since I'm simply reusing the CMakeLists.txt (which I didn't write) that was used to build the old so file. Here's my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.4 )

PROJECT(Fix2Winner2)

SET ( ARCH ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} )
MESSAGE( "******  Machine is : ${ARCH}" )

SET(PROJECT_NAME "Fix2Winner2")

include_directories(
   C:/dev/Fix2Winner2/src
   C:/dev/Fix2Winner2/src/RulesEngine
)

link_directories(
)

SET ( LIB_RULES_SRC
    src/RulesEngine/RuleEngine.cpp
)

SET ( LIB_BCL_RULE_ENGINE_SRC
    src/bcl_rule_engine.cpp
)

add_definitions(  -Wall -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE )

add_library( "fix2winner2_rules" STATIC ${LIB_RULES_SRC} )
add_library( "bcl_rule_engine" SHARED ${LIB_BCL_RULE_ENGINE_SRC} )

target_link_libraries( "bcl_rule_engine" "fix2winner2_rules" )
```

I've not really looked into what those compilation flags do, but they didn't seem to cause any problem. I compiled it on VS's Developer PowerShell by running `cmake .` then `cmake --build . --config Release` and the following output were produced

```
CMake is re-running because C:/dev/Fix2Winner2/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is out-of-date.
  the file 'C:/dev/Fix2Winner2/CMakeLists.txt'
  is newer than 'C:/dev/Fix2Winner2/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp.depend'
  result='-1'
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
******  Machine is : AMD64
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/Fix2Winner2
MSBuild version 17.7.2+d6990bcfa for .NET Framework

  Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/Fix2Winner2/CMakeLists.txt
  RuleEngine.cpp

  Bunch-of-warnings-here...

  fix2winner2_rules.vcxproj -> C:\dev\Fix2Winner2\Release\fix2winner2_rules.lib
  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/Fix2Winner2/CMakeLists.txt
  bcl_rule_engine.vcxproj -> C:\dev\Fix2Winner2\Release\bcl_rule_engine.dll
  Building Custom Rule C:/dev/Fix2Winner2/CMakeLists.txt
```

From an initial look, it seems like the cmake file is compiling two libraries, `fix2winner2_rules` and `bcl_rule_engine`, and then linked the former to the latter. In the original cmake file however, the `fix2winner2_rules` was actually compiled as `SHARED`. I had to change it to `STATIC` because otherwise MSVC compiler would complain about not finding a `.lib` file, making me unable to build the dll. It'd basically show error

```
PS C:\dev\Fix2Winner2> cmake --build . --config Release
MSBuild version 17.7.2+d6990bcfa for .NET Framework

  fix2winner2_rules.vcxproj -> C:\dev\Fix2Winner2\Release\fix2winner2_rules.dll
  bcl_rule_engine.cpp

  Bunch-of-warnings-here...

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Release\fix2winner2_rules.lib' [C:\dev\Fix2Winner2\bcl_rule_engine.vcxproj]
```

Now having compiled the `bcl_rule_engine.dll`, I was using it like this
Fix2Winner2Test.cs

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport(@"C:\\dev\\Fix2Winner2Test\\bcl_rule_engine.dll")] // @"C:\\dev\\Fix2WinnerCS\\Fix2Winner\\bcl_rule_engine.dll"
    private static extern bool init_config_rule_engine(string configFile, int debugMode);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        init_config_rule_engine(@"C:\\dev\\t_equity_wprb_config_ajb.xml", 0);
    }
}
```

Now if I didn't specify the full path i.e. `DllImport("bcl_rule_engine.dll")` it'd give me the error of

```
System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'bcl_rule_engine.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)'
```

And if I do include the full path, it'd tell me

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'init_config_rule_engine' in DLL 'C:\\dev\\Fix2Winner2Test\\bcl_rule_engine.dll'.'
```

And it's still showing the same errors whether or not I bring `fix2winner_rules.lib` into the same dir as `bcl_rule_engine.dll`.

I'm at a lost here. Not sure how to move forward from here. At first I thought my dll was incorrectly and might be missing some dependencies. The online suggested Dependency Walker does not support Windows 10, but I did manage to get https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies installed and ran my dll through it. I'm not familiar with how to use it, but it doesn't seem like it's showing me that I'm missing anything?

[image]

Comment: Presumably you're compiling with MSVC? Does it actually generate a .dll and .lib for the C++ project? Without `__declspec(dllexport)`, I don't know if it will...

Comment: In the dependency viewer, select your dll (bcl_rule_engine.dll) and look at the right side of the output. You should see your method there if it's being exported properly.

Comment: `add_definitions(  -Wall`  the `-Wall` is not a msvc argument.

Comment: By default in msvc it will not export symbols in a dll if you don't tell it to do so. Also when there are no exported symbols it does not create an import library or .exp file.

Comment: MSVC does not generate .lib file unless you have at least one exported function.

Comment: You may want to go through this Microsoft tutorial on how to create a dll: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) it will explain the whole process including the macro used to switch between `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)` after you understand how to do this without CMake you can google the CMake support.